# Error while getting an image reference on Firebase: [Error: firebase.storage().refFromURL(*) unable to parse 'url', ensure it's a valid storage url'.]

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, firebase-storage

My app is feed based. It downloads posts from a firestore table and shows the posts in the app.
I upgraded to React-Native-Firebase because of Expo SDK 49 and now I can't delete an image.

The image is showing fine in the feed.

Here is my delete function:

```
import firestore, { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import { setAnalyticsEvent } from '../../utils/firebase/setAnalyticsEvent';

export const handleDelete = (postId, setDeleting, setCurrentPark, getNewTings) => {
    Alert.alert(
        'Delete post',
        'Are you sure?',
        [
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                onPress: () => {
                    setAnalyticsEvent('Delete_Post_Cancelled', { 'location': 'home' });
                    console.log('PostId: ', postId);
                    console.log('Cancel pressed!')
                },
                style: 'cancel',
            },
            {
                text: 'Confirm',
                onPress: () => {
                    setAnalyticsEvent('Delete_Post_Confirmed', { 'location': 'home' });
                    deletePost(postId, setDeleting, setCurrentPark, getNewTings)
                },
            },
        ],
        { cancelable: false },
    );
};

export const deletePost = async (postId, setDeleting, setCurrentPark, getNewTings) => {
    setDeleting(true);
    console.log('Current Post Id: ', postId);

    const currentPostRef = firestore().collection('posts').doc(postId);
    let currentPosttoDelete = await currentPostRef.get();
    const { postImg, userId } = currentPosttoDelete.data();

    if (postImg != null) {
        console.log('Post image is available');

        try {
            const desertRef = storage().refFromURL(postImg);
            console.log('desertRef', desertRef);

            // Attempt to delete the image
            await desertRef.delete();
            console.log(`${postImg} has been deleted successfully.`);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error while deleting the image or getting the reference: ', e);
            Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an issue deleting the image, but the post will still be deleted.');
        }

    } else {
        console.log('Post image is not available');
    }

    // Regardless of whether the image deletion succeeded or failed, delete the Firestore document
    await deleteFirestoreData(postId, userId);

    if (setCurrentPark != null) {
        getNewTings();
    }

    setDeleting(false);
};


export const deleteFirestoreData = async (postId) => {
    // Set document as deleted 
    await firestore().collection('posts').doc(postId).update({
        deletedTime: new Date(),
        updatedTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    })
        .then(() => {
            Alert.alert(
                'Post deleted!',
                'Your post has been deleted successfully!',
            );
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('Error deleting post.', e));
};
```

When I try and delete a post with an image, and the app reaches this line:

```
const desertRef = storage().refFromURL(postImg);
```

It throws this error:
[Error: firebase.storage().refFromURL(*) unable to parse 'url', ensure it's a valid storage url'.]

The URL is correct and is stored in the same firebase storage instance the app is connected to, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.
In another part of the app, I upload a video to firebase's storage, then send the video to cloudinary and then delete the video off firebase's storage using the same

```
 const desertRef = storage().refFromURL(postImg);
 console.log('desertRef', desertRef);
 await desertRef.delete();
```

and that works.

Is there anything that you can spot as to why it's throwing this error?

Comment: If you call `console.log(postImg);` right before the `const desertRef = storage().refFromURL(postImg);` that raises the error, what value does it output?

Comment: Hi,

Here is what it logs:
https://storage.googleapis.com/latest-sightings-nadav-tuts.appspot.com/tings/Pilanesberg-Game-Reserve/2023/10/25/Elephant/Liberty%C2%A0Church-At%20the%20Bakubung%20Gate-19342.jpg

The link works. But, it can't get the ref.

Without changing anything, this 1 worked: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/latest-sightings-nadav-tuts.appspot.com/o/tings%2FKruger-National-Park%2F2023%2F10%2F26%2FBuffalo%2FAJV23KQzOtSAK5eh9rlhIfDgoty2-negtjg93rlq-59006acb-eefd-4e6e-a5d6-b668974e1969.jpg?alt=media&token=48d808e8-0088-40b0-97bb-6992150434fa

Is it the link?

Comment: Hmm... that URL looks correct. I'm not sure why you get the error then. I hope somebody else spots the problem.